# How to fork/clone an identical Node child process in the same sense as fork() of Linux system call?

Tags: node.js, process, fork

So I was developing a server farm on Node which requires multiple processes per machine to handle the load. Since Windows doesn't quite get along with Node `cluster` module, I had to manually work it out.

The real problem is when I was forking Node processes, a JS module path was required as the first argument to the `child_process.fork()` function and once forked, the child process wouldn't inherit anything from its parent. In my case, I want a function that does similar thing as fork() system call in Linux, which clones the parent process, inherits everything and continues execution from exactly where the fork() is done. Can this be achieved on the Node platform?

Comment: How is windows not getting along with cluster.js? http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html you might need to upgrade node and your modules to the latest versions

Comment: Well, I haven't checked the latest version out but even if it works on Windows, I still need to fork processes in the way mentioned above.

Comment: If this is still relevant, you might look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/posix-fork

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think node.js is ever going to support [fork(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)

The comment from the node github page on the subject

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2334#issuecomment-3153822

> We're not (ever) going to support fork.
>
> not portable to windows
>
> difficult conceptually for users
>
> entire heap will be quickly copied with a compacting VM; no benefits from copy-on-write
>
> not necessary
>
> difficult for us to do

[child_process.fork()](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)

> This is a special case of the spawn() functionality for spawning Node
> processes.  In addition to having all the methods in a normal
> ChildProcess instance, the returned object has a communication channel
> built-in.  See child.send(message, [sendHandle]) for details.

Comment: OK. Now it seems impossible to do fork(2) at JavaScript level. Thanks for digging up the issue comment.